# bcrypt node.js (auto-gen a salt and hash)

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt, salt, saltedhash

I am using the following code to hash (and hopefully salt) user passwords before I store them in my DB.

```
// hash the password before the user is saved
ConsultantSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;

  // hash the password only if the password has been changed or user is new
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  // generate the hash
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {

    if (err) {
      logger.error("bcrypt.hash "+err);
      return next(err);
    } 

    // change the password to the hashed version
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  });
});
```

What I am confused about, is the part

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
```

I got this code from a tutorial and I have seen it quite often searching for an answer.
Based on the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for bcrypt I would have expected the following code

```
const saltrounds = 10;
bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
```

To be working but this breaks my program without an error.

My questions are:
Why are there two "null" arguments? What are they for?
Is the hash salted based on the code with the two nulls?

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: what version of nodejs and bcrypt module are u using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs).  The following code is from their docs at npmjs.com.

### bcrypt hashing

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash)
```

or

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash)
```

### bcrypt-nodejs hashing

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, null, null, function(err, hash)
```

### Explanation

You are looking at the docs for bcrypt, not bcrypt-nodejs.  If you are using node.js, you'll most likely want to use bcrypt-nodejs.  I have multiple projects utilizing its features.  The two `null` fields are for the salt and progress:

- salt - [REQUIRED] - the salt to be used to hash the password.
- progress - a callback to be called during the hash calculation to signify progress

Answer (score 1):

I have used crypto library for hashing and it works great. Here is my code snippet

```js
var salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
var iterations = 10;
var keylen = 20;
crypto.pbkdf2(args.password, salt, iterations, keylen, function(succes, bcryptedPassword) {
                    console.log(bcryptedPassword.toString());
                    //Do actions here

                });
```

Please check if it helps you or not

Comment: You need to specify a digest as the 5th argument of `crypto.pbkdf2`, e.g.  'sha256'

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is from the (abandoned?) bcrypt-nodejs module [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
```

You refer to the docs of the bcrypt module [2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Make sure you're using the right module.